# Export GeoTIFF file(s) from WMS (in QGIS)

Tags: qgis, wms, geotiff-tiff

I have this WMS link: https://www.ign.es/wms/pnoa-historico?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Where I would like to download the "PNOA 2019" layer as GeoTIFF file at the highest possible resolution.

I found the "Save Raster Layer..." in QGIS but I have trouble setting the right resolution parameters. I would simply like the highest available resolution (25cm) and avoid that QGIS resamples any images.

Is there is a way to do this without QGIS, simply from command line?

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: @IanTurton Hmm. What is not reliable about it? I just need aerial RGB images.

Comment: Each tile may be independently stretch or otherwise normalised. Also servers will probably not allow you to down load the whole data set at high resolution

Comment: You can create a polygon grid covering your area of interest and automatically fetch individual rasters over each grid extent using [Atlas](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html). Then merge all rasters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GDAL_TRANSLATE` command line tool to export WMS tiles to GeoTIFF.

First create a WMS description file (I'm using EPSG:3857 here, because the service only offers 3857 and 4326):

```
gdal_translate "WMS:https://www.ign.es/wms/pnoa-historico?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&LAYERS=PNOA2019&SRS=EPSG:3857&format=image/jpeg" pnoa2019.xml -of WMS
```

And create your tiles afterwards:
(the example shows the beautiful Plaza de Espana in Sevilla!)

```
gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES -co JPEG_QUALITY=90 -projwin -666683 4491922 -666250 4491634 -tr 0.25 0.25 pnoa2019.xml sevilla.tif
```

Play with the parameters to get the best result: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html, https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html

Comment: Thank you, great answer! I changed the parameter to `-co COMPRESS=DELFATE and -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB`so that I have lossless compression. Do you think that is okay?

Comment: It's ok, but I guess not necessary for orthofotos. I would use "DEFLATE" compression mainly for images with transparent colors. With "JPEG" compression you get much smaller images.

Comment: But isn't JPEG a lossy compression, and then the image quality is reduced?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but it shouldn't make a big difference. You can increase JPEG_QUALITY to 100 percent, but this will increase the size as well.

Comment: Not sure why you need to export to TIFF, the WMS supports TIFF as an output format

Comment: @nmtoken you are right, the server supports GeoTIFF as well (i.e. https://www.ign.es/wms/pnoa-historico?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-668268.8457922260277%2C4495726.557197899558%2C-667798.9136530514807%2C4495961.232827351429&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&WIDTH=809&HEIGHT=404&LAYERS=PNOA2019&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Ftiff&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE). But IMHO I guess we get more compression options with using gdal_translate instead. The file size of the exported TIF files will be much smaller.